# Compute the number of integers $k$ such that $k\mid{f(k)}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n=2^83^95^{10}7^{11}$ and for $k$ a positive integer let $f(k)$ be the number of integers $0\leq x \leq n$ such that
>   $x^2 \equiv k \pmod{n}$. Compute the number of integers $k$ such that $k\mid{f(k)}$.

I didn't see an easy way of counting the number of solutions $x$ to $x^2 \equiv k \pmod{n}$. If $k = 1$ then we need $n\mid(x^2-1) = (x-1)(x+1)$, but I didn't see how to generalize this argument for an arbitrary $k$.

Comment: isnt the answer clearly infinite? for infinitely many values of $k$ we have $f(k)=0$.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Is there an easy way to prove the existence of a quadratic nonresidue without computation?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb The map $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ $x \mapsto x^2$ is not injective since $\pm 1 \mapsto 1$ so it cannot be surjective either

Comment: heck yeah my man, $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 3$ and hence $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod n$.

Comment: or the other thing works too, also sorry if you aren't a man, I got carried on.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Sorry, I thought you meant for arbitrary $n$, I forgot $n$ was used for the number in the actual question. Deleted!

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo How do there exist infinitely many $k$ for which $f(k) = 0$?

Comment: @user19405892: once you have one quadratic nonresidue (i.e. a $k$ for which $f(k) = 0$), then $k+qn$ is a quadratic nonresidue for each $q \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we are not considering the cases when $f(k) = 0.$ The number of solutions to $x^2 \equiv k$ mod $n$ is usually either $0$ or $16$, so we have to decide whether the divisors of $16$ are squares mod $n$.

Clearly $1,4,16$ are squares. However $2,8$ are not squares because they are already not squares mod $2^8$, since they are odd powers of $2$.

There are special cases when $k \equiv 0$ modulo one of the factors $2^8, 3^9, 5^{10}$, $7^{11}$ in which $f(k)$ can be smaller, but then $k$ is so large that $k | f(k)$ will never occur.